# How do you implement a type trait that takes a type and evaluates a reference if the size of the type is greater than X?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have been implementing several data structure classes that are supposed to be able to hold any type and lately I've been 'upgrading' them with type traits.

I wanted to implement a type trait that prevents very large values from being taken as a hard copy. For example in:

```
template<typename T>
T Max(T a, T b){ return (a < b) ? b : a; }
```

I would not want to take T as a value if T happens to by some chance would happen to have an outrageous size.

Instead I would want something like:

```
template<typename T>
 T Max(ref_if_large<T>::val a, ref_if_large<T>::val b){ return (a < b) ? b : a; }
```

I tried implementing this myself, but I've gotten myself into one of those moments where I'm just not seeing what's wrong.

```
template<typename T, bool cond>
struct ref_if_true {
    using V = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct ref_if_true<T, true> {
    using V = T&;
};

template<typename T>
struct ref_if_large {
    using val = 
        ref_if_true< T, ((sizeof(T)) > (12U))>::V;
};
```

The compiler complains about V not being defined but I can't honestly figure out why.

Comment: You should write `typename` in the last using: `using val = 
        typename ref_if_true< T, ((sizeof(T)) > (12U))>::V;` This is because compiler can't know whether the expression X::V is a type or a function or something else when X is a template type, so you should explicitly state that this is a type.

Comment: What's wrong with just talking as an lvalue reference to const `T`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 it can be the worse choice for small types. Taking by copy guarantees no aliasing and the caller doesn't need to worry about something deep in callee's call stack `const_cast`ing `const` away, which must be a consideration for the optimizer. Chandler Carruth gave talk about this one or two cppcons ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `typename` to tell the compiler that `V` is indeed a type.

```
template<typename T>
struct ref_if_large {
    using val = 
        typename ref_if_true< T, ((sizeof(T)) > (12U))>::V;
};
```

By the way, consider using const references for large types. They'll allow binding to const objects and rvalues.

You could also use an alias template to avoid sprinkling the client code with `typename`s:

```
template<typename T>
using ref_if_large = typename ref_if_true<T, ((sizeof(T)) > (12U))>::V;
```

And if you're taking by reference, you might as well parametrize the return type.

```
template<typename T>
ref_if_large<T> Max(ref_if_large<T> a, ref_if_large<T> b){
    return (a < b) ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip to parametrize the return type. I went with that. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the last definition add `typename` for the dependent type, like this: `using val = typename ref_if_true<blah>::V;`. But seriously, **don't do this** for a max function. There are enough problems with aliasing already, don't add uncertainty about whether there's going to be aliasing or not.

---

The Boost library's [`boost::call_traits<T>::param_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) already does the “best param type” thing.

If one wants to avoid a dependency on Boost then of course it can make sense to invent this again (I've done it myself).

But, it's useful to at least be aware of the Boost functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The specific problem is adequately answered by the other two answers here. It's worth additionally pointing out that `ref_if_true` is a specific version of a type trait that already exists in the standard library: [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <class T, bool cond>
using ref_if_true_t = std::conditional_t<cond, T&, T>;
```

and, as such, doesn't need to exist to begin with:

```
template<typename T>
using ref_if_large_t = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > 12U), T&, T>;
```

or really probably:

```
template<typename T>
using ref_if_large_t = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > 12U), T const&, T>;
```

since reference to non-`const` implies something different.

---

Note: metaprogramming is already hard. It gets harder if you blaze your own trail with your own naming conventions. Metafunctions that yield a type should name it `type` (not `V` or `val`).

Comment: Great point about the naming conventions. `val` is very close to `value`, which is also used, but for, well, values.